# Styling views in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I developed a content type of "sale car". Now I'm developing its view to display a brief list of Car Ads with some basic fields (car, model, color, price, link to full ad) inline of each other like this:

**BMW, 120 d**                           $X,xxx,xxx.xx
**Royal Blue, Automatic,**          View Ad

I'm wondering how can I achieve this style? What style format I should use: Table, Grid or something else? Or do I need to get it done through coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a view that is a list of fields.

Once you've got this, add the relevant fields into the view and you should be done.

Choose the relevant format from the format link, check the preview and you should have your view.

To create the view structure:

```
Node 1                Node 2
Field 1 Field 2       Field 1 Field 2
Field 3 Field 4       Field 3 Field 4
```

Add all four fields to the view. On each one select "exclude from view". At the bottom of the field list, add a new "custom text" field.

Do exclude this one from the view though, that's important.

Go into the custom field and in the textarea you can enter HTML code and use the replacement patterns to output the field.

For example:

```
<h2>[title]</h2>
<ul>
    <li>[field_one_name]</li>
    <li>[field_two_name]</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>[field_three_name]</li>
    <li>[field_four_name]</li>
</ul>
```

Get the name's from the Replacement Patterns box under the textarea.

Then select whatever format you think is right. I think you're after a grid.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Making a view, linking it to relevant content type, and selection of fields is done. Problem is placing fields as per the style I mentioned above. I require two rows and two columns to hold these fields.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal provides a way to style the view.

1. Go to your view.
2. Click on 'Advanced' link at right side.
3. Click on link after the label 'Theme'.
4. You will get the list of templates used to style the view.
5. Create your own template with one of the given name in the list for
   specific fields. e.g. views-view--VIEWNAME.tpl.php
6. You will get the view of your own style.

This is how the Drupal views styling works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Styling views in Drupal 7:

1. Add field(which to display) and check the option "Exclude from display".
2. Now go to "Rewrite Results" and check the option "Rewrite the output of this field"
   and below there is a section called "Replacement patterns" where all the added 
   fields appear as a variable(saying variable just for easy understanding)
   Like :

> [title] == Content:
>
> Title[field_event_date] == Content:
>
> Event Date[body] == Content:
>
> Body[body-value] == Raw value

1. Above there is a text ares called "Text" where you can customise your style 
   for this field(Not good practice follow step 4 for better)and clicl "Apply All".
2. Now add one more field(this is an extra field) called "Global: Custom text"
   DO NOT check "Exclude from display" and below text area called "TEXT"is
   the area where we will be writing our HTML codes for styling the views
   using all the fields which are avalable as token here under the option 
   "Replacement patterns".
3. Click on the "Apply All", And YES its done.So simple and cool na??